# Should I capitalize the term 'superstring revolution'?

Tags: string-theory, terminology

I'm writing an essay in physics and will include the word 'superstring revolution'. There have been two superstring revolutions before. In my understanding, such revolutions changed people's views about string theory and how to unite different branches of the idea. From the [online resources](https://wiki2.org/en/History_of_string_theory), I noticed usually people would not capitalize on this term.

However, I noticed most revolutions are capitalized, so I wonder in physics, is it a convention (not) to capitalize this term? Any suggestions are appreciated:)

Comment: I'm closing this question as off-topic as it appears to be more about the English language than physics.

Comment: You can ask in English SE... or in a new community languages.codidact.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow the conventions of the field. A quick search on Google Scholar indicates that “superstring revolution” is essentially never capitalized in the literature.